# how to store retrieved data to temporary table with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have executed one query  and I want to store that result set into a temporary table and again I want to re filter the  data from temporary table. How can I do this with mysql. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl
SELECT whatever
FROM wherever
WHERE ...
```

Comment: @Barmer  how much time this temporary table exists.

Comment: @Mahendra it exists until you drop your db connection

Comment: @Mahendra It's Barmar, not Barmer. TAB completion is your friend.